# Youtube or dailymotion player api using rules

Tags: youtube-api

I want to develop an app that uses videos issued from dailymotion or youtube.
I wanted to know if there are some conditions or legal rules for using the player api of this sites.
My main question : I want to do an application that act on the video, so the user should look and can't interact. Is it a problem if the user can't act on the video ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YouTube API Terms of Service dictates what you can and can't do using the YouTube Data and Player APIs:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

I can't answer specific legal/policy questions—you should read the ToS for yourself and interpret it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't find this api terms. I will read it !  
Thanks ;)